# centerInParent sets the X-coordinate too much to the right

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to make 2 buttons with 1 textview under each of the buttons align besides each other.

This is my code so far:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    tools:context=".WelcomeActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="a string of text"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:background="#cac09F"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/icon_1">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
            android:background="@mipmap/icon_2">
        </Button>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When i add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for both of the `TextViews` their right edge will be aligned with the right edge of `btn2`.

Heres a picture when `btn1` has `layout_centerInParent="true"` and not `btn2`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context=".WelcomeActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="#cac09F"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="a string of text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/icon_1"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
            android:background="@mipmap/icon_2"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn2"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I used a relative layout as a parent and put the 2 buttons with their below text in 2 different linear layouts.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it. But it works like a charm and that's great for me. Thank you so much for your help.